# Best way to find MIN of a bunch of dates in string format (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, date, string-conversion

Eugh ....

I have a SQL table, with a bunch of strings representing dates in this format: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

I need to find the minimum date, with a very strong preference for doing so in SQL, rather than pulling it into some other language and doing the calculation there (C#, for example).

Any suggestions for the easiest way to do this.

Answers along the lines of "don't store dates in non-standard string formats" are correct but not helpful :(

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Lamak SQL 2014, though I'd be interested to hear any answers for newer versions.

Comment: Could I get an explanation from whoever downvoted the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CONVERT` with [format-style 103](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql):

```
SELECT
MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME, yourColumn, 103))
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set the dateformat of your session and then convert your column to a datetime.

```
set dateformat dmy

select min(convert(datetime, YourColumn))
from YourTable
```

Here is the documentation on dateformat. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql

Comment: OMG ... that looks perfect! What scope does that get changed in? It looks like you're saying it's just that query session? Do you have a citation for that? (Looking on Google right now, but haven't found an answer yet.)

Comment: I should add that if at all possible it would make things easier if you can change the datatype but it seems you already know that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the strings do dates using the `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` function then the miniumum

```
CREATE TABLE #DateString (
    StringDate CHAR(19)
)

INSERT INTO #DateString
VALUES
('23/10/2017 10:22:10'),
('23/10/2017 10:23:10'),
('23/10/2017 10:26:10'),
('23/10/2017 10:25:10')

SELECT
    MIN(DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
        SUBSTRING(StringDate, 7,4),
        SUBSTRING(StringDate, 4,2),
        SUBSTRING(StringDate, 1,2),
        SUBSTRING(StringDate, 12,2),
        SUBSTRING(StringDate, 15,2),
        SUBSTRING(StringDate, 18,2),
        0
    ))
FROM
    #DateString
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a sample proc:

```
begin 
DECLARE @Date varchar(25)
set @Date='23/10/2017 10:30:30'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @Date, 103)
end
```

O/P

```
DateTimeField
2017-10-23 10:30:30.000
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the dates to numeric form such as epoch or difference from certain date, then sort by their corresponding numeric value.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem for the OP is converting these strings to dates. If they are in the date(time) datatype converting to epoch is just an extra step.